# presentModalViewController can't display view controller for the second time

Tags: iphone

I am using a tab bar controller. In the tab bar, I'm having one view. In that tab, I call one function using `NSTimer` and it opens another view controller.

```
First * sVC = [[First alloc] initWithNibName:@"First" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
[self presentModalViewController:sVC animated:YES];
```

This opens a view controller that has one button. When the user clicks that button, I want to close the view and call `NSTimer`.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]
```

The problem is that at the first time, the view opened and closed, but the second time, the view could not open.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814126/using-presentmodalviewcontroller-to-load-a-view/1818086#1818086) might be helpful to you.